# Add a variable to a data frame containing max value of each row

Tags: r

I want to add a variable (column) to a dataframe (`df`), containing in each row the maximum value of that row across 2nd to 26th column.

For the first row, the code would be:

```
df$max[1] <- max(df[1,2:26])
```

I am looking for a way to generalize that for rows 1 to 865. If I give:

```
df$max[1:865] <- max(df[1:865, 2:26])
```

I get the overall max across all rows for the variable `df$max`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use `apply`.  For instance:

```
df[, "max"] <- apply(df[, 2:26], 1, max)
```

Here's a basic example:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=1:50, b=rnorm(50), c=rpois(50, 10))
> df$max <- apply(df, 1, max)
> head(df, 2)
  a          b  c max
1 1  1.3527115  9   9
2 2 -0.6469987 20  20
> tail(df, 2)
    a          b  c max
49 49 -1.4796887 10  49
50 50  0.1600679 13  50
```

Comment: what if i want the name of the column in max for each row.. for example df$max[1] = c

Comment: what if I need to add na.rm = TRUE ?

Answer (score 43):

Vectorized version with `pmax`:

```
df$max <- do.call(pmax, df[2:26])
```

In case when you need omit `NA` values syntax is:

```
do.call(pmax, c(df[2:26], list(na.rm=TRUE)))
```

The second argument of `do.call` need to be a list of arguments to function. `df` is already list so we concatenate it with `na.rm=TRUE` argument (converted to list).

Comment: wich one of the two version is faster between the `pmax` and the `apply` version? I have to do it for thousands of coolums

Comment: millions. I tried and pmax appears to be significantly quicker. Now I am struggling to find a way to omit missing values `df$max <- do.call(pmax, df[2:26],na.rm=TRUE)` does not seem to work any idea why?

Comment: @Alex Yes, semantic is weird and help page not clear. This works: `do.call(pmax, c(df[2:26], list(na.rm=TRUE)))`. Second argument of `do.call` should be list of arguments to function, so you need all arguments, with `na.rm` in the one list.

Comment: @Alex `df` is a list (as every `data.frame`), `list(na.rm=TRUE)` is another, `c` concatenate them into the one.

Answer (score 8):

Here are two additional methods. The first,in base R, is to combine matrix extraction `[` with `max.col`, which returns a vector indexing the column position of the maximum value in each row.

```
df$max <- df[2:26][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), max.col(df[2:26]))]
```

`cbind` constructs a matrix indexing the position of the maximum value for each row and `[` uses this to extract this value.

The second is to use `rowMaxs` in the `matrixStats` package. This looks like

```
library(matrixStats)
rowMaxs(as.matrix(df[2:26])))
```

---

Let's do some benchmarking.

```
# data.frame with 1000 observations and 26 variables
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(id=paste0(letters[-1], 1:40), matrix(rnorm(25000L, 5L, 10L), 1000L))
```

Also add the `rowMaxs` function from the `matrixStats` package to the mix.

```
library(matrixStats)
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(apply=apply(df[, 2:26], 1, max),
               pmax=do.call(pmax, df[2:26]),
               max.colSub=df[2:26][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), max.col(df[2:26]))],
               rowMaxs=rowMaxs(as.matrix(df[2:26])))
Unit: microseconds
        expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
       apply 1610.540 1786.5905 2193.5334 1863.5680 1990.4380 6915.999   100   c
        pmax  354.382  364.6455  380.1720  373.3405  385.4580  567.923   100 a  
  max.colSub  604.416  651.7430  822.6015  664.7155  681.2510 3086.512   100  b 
     rowMaxs  243.762  264.0040  320.2350  277.9750  290.5190 2328.712   100 a
```

So, `rowMaxs` is the clear winner followed by `pmax` and then by `max.col`, with matrix extraction, and `apply` at the tail end of the pack.

With a data.frame with 10000 rows and 26 columns, we get a similar story:

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(id=paste0(letters[-1], 1:400), matrix(rnorm(250000L, 5L, 10L), 10000L))
```

The above code returns

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
      apply 15.193361 18.299830 21.737516 20.337880 21.774793 99.44836   100   c
       pmax  3.060853  3.101481  3.156630  3.137545  3.191430  3.54182   100 a  
 max.colSub  3.338828  3.642603  7.051700  3.992708  6.336531 84.43119   100  b 
    rowMaxs  1.244184  1.322302  2.675281  1.508474  1.638053 79.28054   100 a
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse` you can try the following:

**considering all numeric columns**

```
df %>%
  keep(is.numeric) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(maxval = max(across()))
```

**in your specific case**

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(maxval = max(across(2:26)))
```

Note: For tons of rows, the `rowwise()` operation will slow down your analysis.

Comment: Useful to have this tidyverse answer as well. How can we include na.rm?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an example that uses column names instead of indices, here's a simple solution. Example is if you're trying to create a new column "MaxOfColumns" that calculates the maximum of "Col1", "Col2", and "Col3":

```
df$MaxOfColumns <- pmax(df$Col1, df$Col2, df$Col3)
```