# Finding the maximum value for each row among 3 columns in R

Tags: r, max

I need to calculate the maximum value for each row among 3 columns.

A table could be:

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5 ) 
y = c(2,3,3,1,1 ) 
z = c(4,3,2,1,1 ) 
df<-data.frame(x,y,z)
```

I need to get:

```
    x   y   z   max
1   1   2   4   4
2   2   3   3   3
3   3   3   2   3
4   4   1   1   4
5   5   1   1   5
```

I tried:

```
df$max<-max(x, y,z)
```

But I get:

```
  x y z max
1 1 2 4   5
2 2 3 3   5
3 3 3 2   5
4 4 1 1   5
5 5 1 1   5
```

So, how can I do this correctly?

Comment: `df$max<-apply(X=df, MARGIN=1, FUN=max)`

Comment: Take a look at `?pmax`

Comment: @GabyP I just ran it on my machine and it works fine - you might want to try again in a new R session.

Comment: sorry, @JohnPaul My fault. If you post it I'll vote it. It does work.

Comment: Yes it works but it's the slowest of the 3 ways benchmarked by akrun. (and mine is the fastest :))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a variable to a data frame containing max value of each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071271/add-a-variable-to-a-data-frame-containing-max-value-of-each-row)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `apply` function for this like so:

```
df$max<-apply(X=df, MARGIN=1, FUN=max)
```

The `MARGIN=1` argument indicated that for every row in `X` you wish to apply the function in `FUN`. If you use `MARGIN=2` it will be by column or MARGIN=`c(1,2)` it will be both rows and columns.

Comment: what about the second largest one of each row?

Answer (score 12):

Use data.table :)

```
library(data.table)
x = c(1,2,3,4,5 ) 
y = c(2,3,3,1,1 ) 
z = c(4,3,2,1,1 ) 
dt<-data.table(x,y,z)
dt[, max:=pmax(x,y,z)]
dt
```

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
 df$max <- do.call(`pmax`, df)
 df
 #  x y z max
 #1 1 2 4   4
 #2 2 3 3   3
 #3 3 3 2   3
 #4 4 1 1   4
 #5 5 1 1   5
```

#### Benchmarks

```
 set.seed(49)
 df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:20, 1e5*3,replace=TRUE), ncol=3))
 f1 <- function() df$max <- apply(df, 1, max)
 f2 <- function() df$max <- do.call(`pmax`, df)
 f3 <- function() setDT(df)[, max:=pmax(V1,V2,V3)]

 library(microbenchmark)
 microbenchmark(f1(), f2(),f3(), unit="relative", times=25)
 #Unit: relative
 # expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
 # f1() 48.143635 48.287875 46.031638 32.868138 8.922203    25
 # f2()  1.269581  1.373479  1.654625  2.324896 1.182107    25
 # f3()  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000 1.000000    25
```

Answer (score 4):

With dplyr 1.0.0

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(max = max(x, y, z))
```

Answer (score 1):

If John posts accept his, but just to show the result his comment does work

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5 ) 
y = c(2,3,3,1,1 ) 
z = c(4,3,2,1,1 ) 
df<-data.frame(x,y,z)

df$max<-apply(df, 1, max)
df$max
#[1] 4 3 3 4 5


df
#x y z max
#1 2 4   4
#2 3 3   3
#3 3 2   3
#4 1 1   4
#5 1 1   5
```