# Writing the return of an R loop function into a vector

Tags: r

I keep on getting below output:

```
[1]  0  0  0 22
```

instead of

```
[1]  19  21 21 22
```

for the max number per row in below "data" file:

```
  A  B  C
1 1 19 10
2 2 20 11
3 3 21 12
4 4 22 13
```

function used:

```
f <- function(x) {
     for (i in 1:4) z<- x[i,1:3] 
         count <- max(z)
         y<- vector(length = 4)  
         y[i] <- count
     return(print(y)) 
 }
```

to run the function:

```
 f5 <- f(data)
```

the question is how to let the system write each loop output in the vector and not erase any loop output !

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Is this more so you can understand how `for` loops work in `R`, or are you just after the answer: `apply(df, 1, max)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the maximun value for each row among 3 columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935134/finding-the-maximun-value-for-each-row-among-3-columns-in-r) OR [Add a variable to a data frame containing max value of each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071271/add-a-variable-to-a-data-frame-containing-max-value-of-each-row)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't need a loop, just use `pmax`

```
do.call(pmax, df1)
#[1] 19 20 21 22
```

---

If we need to use a `for` loop, it is better to create a `vector` of length equal to the number of rows of the dataset ('v') and assign each element of 'v' with the `max` that we get from looping through each row

```
f <- function(dat) {
 v <- numeric(nrow(dat))
 for (i in seq_len(nrow(dat))) { 
    v[i] <- max(unlist(dat[i,]))
  }
  v
}

f(df1)
#[1] 19 20 21 22
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that solved my problem

Comment: Arun I think we meet in user! in Brussels; what if I would like to retrieve the top two or three max values per row !!

Comment: @jean You got the wrong Arun.  I have never been Brussels

Comment: @jean For finding the top 3 max rows, try `apply(df1, 1, function(x) head(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE), 3))`

Comment: thanks but it filters my 4th row because we input 3 at the end; well as I need an output of same all rows (mean 4) and three/two columns that are the top max values

Comment: @jean HOw does it filter 4th row?  I used `head(., 3)`

Comment: Akrun, You are right, I am terribly sorry; I suppose I just need to transpose the output to make more sense to me

Comment: @jean It's okay.  Ya, i forgot about the transpose when using `apply` with `MARGIN = 1`

Comment: it works with t(apply()) but for the following data set                              df1 <- data.frame(A = c(19,2,3,22), B = c(1,20,12,13) , C = c(10,11,21,4) )   A  B  C
1 19  1 10
2  2 20 11
3  3 12 21
4 22 13  4

Comment: @jean What is the problem with the `df1` I get `t(apply(df1, 1, function(x) head(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE), 3)))#  [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   19   10    1
[2,]   20   11    2
[3,]   21   12    3
[4,]   22   13    4`

Comment: In fact I need a final output that looks more like below to be able to retrieve also the names of each max col in a separate column:                 [1] [2] [3] [4]
[1,]   19   A   10  C
[2,]   20   B   11  C  
[3,]   21   C   12  B 
[4,]   22   A   13  B

Comment: If you need the max column name, then `names(df1)[max.col(df1, "first")]`

Comment: Last question: is it possible to retrieve all together the name of the first "max value" and name of "second max value" ??? (ideally in 4 columns with corresponding name and value). I suppose we need to do a loop function !

Comment: Thanks question is solved