# Code correct on laptop and error on Microsoft azure

Tags: r, azure

I need higher computational power to run my algorithms. I created an account on Microsoft Azure and a virtual machine which runs a RStudio pro session.

However, my algorithm works perfectly on my laptop, but produces an error on Azure, even though I use the exact same data and code.

Plus, the error is very disturbing since my code creates a dataframe which is loaded into a `max()` function. The error is that the argument is a list. The weirdest is that it appears as a list in the environment, but as a dataframe when I apply the `class()`function.

Have you experimented the same problem? Do you maybe advise me to use the free Rstudio session on AWS?

The code:

```
df = list(c(5,10),c(11,8))

a = matrix(df[[1]], ncol = 2)
b = matrix(df[[2]], ncol = 2)

   result = NULL
   for (i in 1:2) {
      l = max(a[,i],b[,i])
      result = unname(cbind(result,l))
   }
```

On my laptop I obtain `c(11,10)` and on the cloud I receive this error:

```
Error in max(a[, i], b[, i]) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument r
```

The session on Azure:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C          
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] abind_1.4-5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.4 tools_3.4.4
```

The session on my laptop:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rapport_1.0    geometry_0.4.2 plyr_1.8.4     broom_0.5.2    ggplot2_3.2.0  abind_1.4-5   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2       magrittr_1.5     magic_1.5-9      tidyselect_0.2.5 munsell_0.5.0   
 [6] colorspace_1.4-1 lattice_0.20-38  R6_2.4.0         rlang_0.4.0      stringr_1.4.0   
[11] dplyr_0.8.3      tools_3.6.1      grid_3.6.1       gtable_0.3.0     nlme_3.1-140    
[16] withr_2.1.2      yaml_2.2.0       digest_0.6.20    lazyeval_0.2.2   assertthat_0.2.1
[21] tibble_2.1.3     crayon_1.3.4     purrr_0.3.2      tidyr_0.8.3      rapportools_1.0 
[26] glue_1.3.1       stringi_1.4.3    pander_0.6.3     compiler_3.6.1   pillar_1.4.2    
[31] generics_0.0.2   scales_1.0.0     backports_1.1.4  pkgconfig_2.0.2
```

Comment: Hi Simon, Can you show us a reproducible example along with any error messages you get? See this link : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello, there is no particular example you could run. I am wondering if a difference can occur between Rstudio on a local computer and the same code on the online version ?

Comment: what I mean is, Try a smaller reprodicible piece of code based on what you think is producing error. Run it on your local system as well as the server and edit your post to show us the code and corresponding outputs including any errors.

Comment: Also, try running `sessionInfo()` to see any differences between the versions of R and any packages you may be using.

Comment: The question is updated! Also, the R version on my laptop is 3.6.1, but on the cloud it is 3.4.something. However, for such very simple operation like `max()`, I do not see why there would be a difference between the two versions...

Comment: Your R code as written doesn't work on my laptop.  The data frames a and b only have one column each.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @DavidKlotz, I updated the problem. I simply want to take two matrices 1x2, and create a new pair that is the highest per column for the 2 matrices. Does it work on your laptop now?

Comment: Yes, and you still get the same error in Azure?

Comment: Yes, which I totally don't understand, since data is the same... I also updated in the question the session info, if it can be of any help to understand the problem.

Comment: Still do not know why there is a difference, but I simply `unlist()` the output of the list and created a matrix. Now it works. Thank for the help anyway!

Comment: I don't understand the Azure disconnect, but the sample code seems overly complicated.  If you just want the max elements of the two items in your list (df), you can do `lapply(df, max)`.  If you want the maximum for each row of an existing matrix, [these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935134/finding-the-maximum-value-for-each-row-among-3-columns-in-r) are all much simpler