# How to create a new column based on the values in other columns in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe "df" like following. First column is the Samples. I wanted to create a new column based on the values in other columns.

```
Input:

Sample  Region4 Region1 Region5 Region3 Region2 Type
T1       0       0.289    0.378   0       1      K
T2       0       0.167     0     0.875  0.389    K
T3    0.186     0.12345    0      0     0.187    K
T4   0.11234     0.1789    0     0.457  0.786    L
T5    0.2347     0.2567    0      0       0      L
T6   0.28769       0     0.123   0.1987 0.1565   L
T7    0.142        0     0.1987   0       0      M
T8       0       0.1256  0.123   0.129   0.111   M
T9    0.187      0.987     0     0.237   0.783   M
```

In the "New" column "0" should be assigned if the sample showing value <0.2 in at least one of the Regions and "2" should be assigned if the sample showing value >=0.2 in at least one of the Regions. It should look like following:

Output:

```
Sample  Region4 Region1 Region5 Region3 Region2 Type  New
T1       0       0.289    0.378   0       1      K     2
T2       0       0.167     0     0.875  0.389    K     2
T3    0.186     0.12345    0      0     0.187    K     0
T4   0.11234     0.1789    0     0.457  0.786    L     2
T5    0.2347     0.2567    0      0       0      L     2
T6   0.28769       0     0.123   0.1987 0.1565   L     2
T7    0.142        0     0.1987   0       0      M     0
T8       0       0.1256  0.123   0.129   0.111   M     0
T9    0.187      0.987     0     0.237   0.783   M     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this in a vectorized way with `rowSums`

```
nm1 <- startsWith(names(df1), "Region")
df1$New <- c(0, 2)[(rowSums(df1[nm1] >=0.2) !=0)+1]
df1$New
#[1] 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 0 2
```

---

Or another option with `Reduce`

```
c(0, 2)[Reduce(`|`, lapply(df1[nm1], `>=`, 0.2)) + 1]
#[1] 2 2 0 2 2 2 0 0 2
```

Comment: Hey Thanks. This is done in row wise, but I want this to be done column wise, and then assign values in "New" column. Could you please tell how to do this.

Comment: @raju Seems like your expected output is based on the row wise logic

Comment: Yes, but could you tell me how to give it column wise logic..Thankyou

Comment: Should I post this column wise logic as a new question?

Comment: @raju Based on the example you provided, the column wise logic won't work

Comment: What if you transpose and then do this?

Comment: @raju Problem is with the number of columns, and the number of rows, If you want to create a new column, it should be equal to the number of columns

Comment: Ok, I understand. Could you tell me how to sort the values >=0.2 in the decreasing order in the "Region" columns

Comment: @raju Please edit your question to update the post with the expected output.  It is not clear from your comments

Comment: I will write a new question

Answer (score 0):

basically I used [Add a variable to a data frame containing max value of each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071271/add-a-variable-to-a-data-frame-containing-max-value-of-each-row) to get max value of each row and then used an ifelse to get the New column

```
        > so1=read.csv("so1.csv")
        > so1
           Sample Region4 Region1 Region5 Region3 Region2 Type
        1      T1 0.00000 0.28900  0.3780  0.0000  1.0000    K
        2      T2 0.00000 0.16700  0.0000  0.8750  0.3890    K
        3      T3 0.18600 0.12345  0.0000  0.0000  0.1870    K
        4      T4 0.11234 0.17890  0.0000  0.4570  0.7860    L
        5      T5 0.23470 0.25670  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000    L
        6      T6 0.28769 0.00000  0.1230  0.1987  0.1565    L
        7      T7 0.14200 0.00000  0.1987  0.0000  0.0000    M
        8      T8 0.00000 0.12560  0.1230  0.1290  0.1110    M
        9      T9 0.18700 0.98700  0.0000  0.2370  0.7830    M


    > so1$new1=do.call(pmax,so1[2:6])
    > so1
      Sample Region4 Region1 Region5 Region3 Region2 Type    new1
    1     T1 0.00000 0.28900  0.3780  0.0000  1.0000    K 1.00000
    2     T2 0.00000 0.16700  0.0000  0.8750  0.3890    K 0.87500
    3     T3 0.18600 0.12345  0.0000  0.0000  0.1870    K 0.18700
    4     T4 0.11234 0.17890  0.0000  0.4570  0.7860    L 0.78600
    5     T5 0.23470 0.25670  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000    L 0.25670
    6     T6 0.28769 0.00000  0.1230  0.1987  0.1565    L 0.28769
    7     T7 0.14200 0.00000  0.1987  0.0000  0.0000    M 0.19870
    8     T8 0.00000 0.12560  0.1230  0.1290  0.1110    M 0.12900
    9     T9 0.18700 0.98700  0.0000  0.2370  0.7830    M 0.98700

> so1$New=ifelse(so1$new1>=0.2,2,0)
> so1
  Sample Region4 Region1 Region5 Region3 Region2 Type    new1 New
1     T1 0.00000 0.28900  0.3780  0.0000  1.0000    K 1.00000   2
2     T2 0.00000 0.16700  0.0000  0.8750  0.3890    K 0.87500   2
3     T3 0.18600 0.12345  0.0000  0.0000  0.1870    K 0.18700   0
4     T4 0.11234 0.17890  0.0000  0.4570  0.7860    L 0.78600   2
5     T5 0.23470 0.25670  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000    L 0.25670   2
6     T6 0.28769 0.00000  0.1230  0.1987  0.1565    L 0.28769   2
7     T7 0.14200 0.00000  0.1987  0.0000  0.0000    M 0.19870   0
8     T8 0.00000 0.12560  0.1230  0.1290  0.1110    M 0.12900   0
9     T9 0.18700 0.98700  0.0000  0.2370  0.7830    M 0.98700   2
> so1$new1=NULL
> so1
  Sample Region4 Region1 Region5 Region3 Region2 Type New
1     T1 0.00000 0.28900  0.3780  0.0000  1.0000    K   2
2     T2 0.00000 0.16700  0.0000  0.8750  0.3890    K   2
3     T3 0.18600 0.12345  0.0000  0.0000  0.1870    K   0
4     T4 0.11234 0.17890  0.0000  0.4570  0.7860    L   2
5     T5 0.23470 0.25670  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000    L   2
6     T6 0.28769 0.00000  0.1230  0.1987  0.1565    L   2
7     T7 0.14200 0.00000  0.1987  0.0000  0.0000    M   0
8     T8 0.00000 0.12560  0.1230  0.1290  0.1110    M   0
9     T9 0.18700 0.98700  0.0000  0.2370  0.7830    M   2
```