# max.col with the value not the index

Tags: r, dplyr

If I have a matrix:

```
mod_xgb_softprob$pred[1:3,1:3]
             [,1]         [,2]         [,3]
[1,] 6.781361e-04 6.781361e-04 6.781422e-04
[2,] 2.022457e-07 2.022457e-07 4.051039e-07
[3,] 6.714367e-04 6.714367e-04 6.714399e-04
```

Generated by:

```
> dput(mod_xgb_softprob$pred[1:3,1:3])
structure(c(0.00067813612986356, 2.02245701075299e-07, 0.000671436660923064, 
0.00067813612986356, 2.02245701075299e-07, 0.000671436660923064, 
0.000678142241667956, 4.05103861567113e-07, 0.000671439862344414
), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))
```

I can transform it into a data frame and get the column with the highest value:

```
x <- mymatrix %>% as.data.frame %>% mutate(max_prob = max.col(., ties.method = "last"))
```

Looks like this:

```
> x
            V1           V2           V3 max_prob
1 6.781361e-04 6.781361e-04 6.781422e-04        3
2 2.022457e-07 2.022457e-07 4.051039e-07        3
3 6.714367e-04 6.714367e-04 6.714399e-04        3
```

If I wanted max_prob to be the actual value not the column index, how would I do that?

Comment: matrix indexing: `mod_xgb_softprob[cbind(1:nrow(mod_xgb_softprob), max.col(mod_xgb_softprob))]`.

Comment: This is a [highly related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071271/add-a-variable-to-a-data-frame-containing-max-value-of-each-row/46060812#46060812). In it, I've added timings for these methods for data.frames of varying sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind base R you can use apply. For example:

```
> x <- matrix(rnorm(9), ncol = 3)
> apply(x, 1, max)
[1] 0.246652 1.063506 2.148525
```

gives the maximum of the column vectors of `x`.

Comment: I think you mean `apply(x, 1, max)`. then the result would be `cbind(x,apply(x, 1, max))`.

Answer (score 2):

Beside the `apply` method from @Mariane and matrix indexing from @lmo's comment, you can also use `matrixStats::rowMaxs`:

```
matrixStats::rowMaxs(mymatrix)
# [1] 6.781422e-04 4.051039e-07 6.714399e-04
```

---

If you have a data frame, you can use `do.call(pmax, ...)` to calculate the parallel maxima of the input columns:

```
mymatrix %>% as.data.frame %>% mutate(max_val = do.call(pmax, .))

#            V1           V2           V3      max_val
#1 6.781361e-04 6.781361e-04 6.781422e-04 6.781422e-04
#2 2.022457e-07 2.022457e-07 4.051039e-07 4.051039e-07
#3 6.714367e-04 6.714367e-04 6.714399e-04 6.714399e-04
```

Comment: Thank a lot this is great. Especially like the do.call() in that it fits neatly with less typing but went with Marianne for no reason other than she was first to answer. Incidentally, I thought do.call() only worked on lists? Always struggled to get my head around exactly what it does and I only tend to use it when copy pasting someone else's code

Comment: Plz feel free to accept @Marianne's answer which is the first correct answer here. In R data.frame is implemented as a list, you can see this more clearly if you do `unclass(df)`;so `do.call` work on data frame as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another option which uses `max.col`, `seq_along` and mathematics. If `m` is your matrix, then the following works as well:

```
mc <- max.col(m, ties.method = 'last')
m[(mc - 1) * nrow(m) + seq_along(mc)]
```

The result:

```
[1] 6.781422e-04 4.051039e-07 6.714399e-04
```

With `cbind` you can than bind this result to the matrix again:

```
> cbind(m, m[(mc - 1) * nrow(m) + seq_along(mc)])
             [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]
[1,] 6.781361e-04 6.781361e-04 6.781422e-04 6.781422e-04
[2,] 2.022457e-07 2.022457e-07 4.051039e-07 4.051039e-07
[3,] 6.714367e-04 6.714367e-04 6.714399e-04 6.714399e-04
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation on @h3rm4n's answer, but you can use a special kind of matrix subsetting as well:

```r
> x[cbind(1:nrow(x), max.col(x))]
[1] 6.781361e-04 4.051039e-07 6.714367e-04
```

Using an index like `cbind(i, j)` extracts row `i` and column `j` for each entry in the resulting matrix.