# Calculating percentage value (based on maximum value) for each element in df; however in specified columns

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, lapply

without complex explanation, let's create small exemplary data frame:

```
A <- c(1,2,3,4)
B <- c(3,4,5,7)
C <- c(3,4,7,3)
D <- c(8,3,2,4)
df <- data.frame(A,B,C,D)

> df
  A B C D
1 1 3 3 8
2 2 4 4 3
3 3 5 7 2
4 4 7 3 4
```

I'd like to calculate percentage values in columns A, B and C using `apply` functions. Percentage value based on maximum value from each row, in other words:

```
%_to_be_calculated <- df[i,j] * 100 / max(df[i,1:3])
```

where `j` index of column `A,` `B` or `C`; `i` subsequent rows in table.

**Desired output:**

```
  A     B       C       D
1 33.33 100     100     8
2 50    100     100     3
3 42.85 71.42   100     2
4 57.14 100     42.85   4
```

**My solution**:

```
apply(df,1,function(i) lapply(i[1:3],function(j) j*100/max(i[1:3])))
```

It works, however it returns list of lists...I'd like to have a nice df, could you give me a clue how to replace the values in current df?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.

The normal `apply` way :

```
df[1:3] <- t(apply(df[1:3], 1, function(x) x/max(x) * 100))
df

#         A         B         C D
#1 33.33333 100.00000 100.00000 8
#2 50.00000 100.00000 100.00000 3
#3 42.85714  71.42857 100.00000 2
#4 57.14286 100.00000  42.85714 4
```

which can be also done by :

```
df[1:3] <- df[1:3] * 100/apply(df[1:3], 1, max)
```

---

A faster approach would be using `do.call` and `pmax`

```
df[1:3] <- df[1:3] * 100 /do.call(pmax, df[1:3])
```

Comment: Also `df[-4] / matrixStats::rowMaxs(as.matrix(df[-4]))`

Comment: Thanks for help! I have to take a closer look to `pmax` and `do.call` in this context.

Answer (score 1):

using data.table:

```
df <- data.table(A,B,C,D)
df[,
   c(
     lapply(.SD, function(x) x/do.call(pmax,.SD[,.(A,B,C)])*100),
     D=list(D)
     ),
   .SDcols=c('A','B','C')
   ]
```

Comment: But this gives different results.

Answer (score 1):

While I do love the `do.call()`+`pmax()` solution --- often when you have the problem well-defined the easiest solution is to wrap it in loops and later think about how to optimize.

```
df2 <- df
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  mi <- max(df[i, 1:3])
  for (j in 1:3) {
    df2[i, j] <- df[i, j] * 100 / mi
  }
}
df2
         A         B         C D
1 33.33333 100.00000 100.00000 8
2 50.00000 100.00000 100.00000 3
3 42.85714  71.42857 100.00000 2
4 57.14286 100.00000  42.85714 4
```

This breaks the problem down and you can see the inner loop is very easy to vectorize:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  mi <- max(df[i, 1:3]) 
  df2[i, 1:3] <- df[i, 1:3] * 100 / mi
}
```

Now your problem is just how to find the maximum of each row more efficiently which [turns out many people have thought about before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071271/add-a-variable-to-a-data-frame-containing-max-value-of-each-row).

Comment: Sorry if this comes across as condescending, my intent is to help by sharing the principle too.