# Finding the Max value for a every row in a range of columns

Tags: r, max, row, multiple-columns

I have a data frame containing some 900 rows and a dozen or so columns. Columns #7 - #11 (so from 7 and up to 11) contain numbers between 0 and 100 inclusive. What I want to know is how I can find:

a) the maximum value of the specified range of columns for each row

b) which column has the max (i.e. column #8 has a value of 100 therefore it contains the highest number)

So, for example, I would like it to return something like: Row #142 has its max value in column #9 or Row #748 has its max value in column #6, etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071271/add-a-variable-to-a-data-frame-containing-max-value-of-each-row

Answer (score 2):

```
index = 7:11
```

a) max value for a specified range of columns

```
apply(dataframe[,index], 1, max)
```

b) max index

```
apply(dataframe[,index], 1, which.max)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowMaxs`

```
library(matrixStats)
index <- 7:11
rowMaxs(as.matrix(df1[, index]))
```

Or with `pmax`

```
do.call(pmax, df1[, index]))
```